# How to synchronize equal lines in two stringlists

Tags: algorithm, delphi, tstringlist

I have two stringlists that I wish to synchronize, so that equal lines get the same index, while different lines will be kept in the list where they originally were, and the other stringlist should get a "filler" for that index. Consider this example:

```
SL1:  1,1,2,3,5,8 
SL2:  1,3,5,7,9

procedure SyncStringlists(aSL1,aSL2 : TStringList; aFill : string = '-');
```

The procedure should change the lists to this

```
SL1:  1,1,2,3,5,8,-,-
SL2:  1,-,-,3,5,-,7,9
```

or, if the lists are sorted, to this

```
SL1:  1,1,2,3,5,-,8,-
SL2:  1,-,-,3,5,7,',9
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "if the lists are sorted". Your examples have the same input data and both lists are ordered.

Comment: Sorry. If (aSL1.Sorted and aSL2.Sorted) the procedure should fill list 1 or 2 based on alphabetized order, but if the lists are not sorted, list2 should be filled, and list 1 should be padded. This is not an important requirement.

Comment: To clarify more: In both the examples from the question, the lists are synchronized, but only in the second example are the "union of the lists" sorted.

Comment: What ordering do you want for '2' and '11'. Simple string comparison gives '11'<'2'. Are your items strings or integers?

Comment: String sorting is fine. I just did numbers for this example. In the actual application I will use it to deal with "real" strings.

Comment: What should the output be when SL2 is 1,3,5,3,3?

Comment: In that case the synced lists would be "1,1,2,3,5,8,-,-" and "1,-,-,3,5,-,3,3", but I see that there could be a multitude of interpretations. In actual use the lists will be sorted, so a solution for that case would be the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for the case where your lists are monotone increasing.

```
procedure SyncStringlists(SL1, SL2: TStringList; const Fill: string='-');
var
  i1, i2: Integer;
begin
  i1 := 0;
  i2 := 0;
  while (i1<SL1.Count) and (i2<SL2.Count) do begin
    if SL1[i1]<SL2[i2] then begin
      SL2.Insert(i2, Fill);
    end else if SL1[i1]>SL2[i2] then begin
      SL1.Insert(i1, Fill);
    end;
    inc(i1);
    inc(i2);
  end;
  while SL1.Count<SL2.Count do begin
    SL1.Add(Fill);
  end;
  while SL2.Count<SL1.Count do begin
    SL2.Add(Fill);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think we came up with almost the same solution :-)

Comment: Nice and simple implementation of what we used to call "balanced line" processing of one or more input files (back in my Cobol days...)

Answer (score 3):

I actually managed to make a method that suits my need:

```
procedure SyncStringlists(aSL1,aSL2 : TStringList; aFill : string = '-');
var
  I,J : integer;
begin
  I := 0;
  J := 0;

  aSL1.Sort;
  aSL2.Sort;

  while (I<aSL1.Count) and (J<aSL2.Count) do
  begin
    if aSL1[I] > aSL2[J] then
      aSL1.Insert(I,aFill)
    else if aSL1[I] < aSL2[J] then
      aSL2.Insert(J,aFill);

    inc(I);
    inc(J);
  end;

  while aSL1.Count < aSL2.Count do aSL1.Add(aFill);
  while aSL2.Count < aSL1.Count do aSL2.Add(aFill);
end;
```

It requires the lists to be sorted, but NOT to have the sorted property true (because then we can't insert into it)

Sample run:

```
SL1: 1,1,2,3,5,8,a,b,c,d,e,f
SL2: 1,3,5,7,9,e,f,g,h,i
```

synced:

```
SL1: 1,1,2,3,5,-,8,-,a,b,c,d,e,f,-,-,-
SL2: 1,-,-,3,5,7,-,9,-,-,-,-,e,f,g,h,i
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope some kind of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (Levenshtein distance) algorithm can help you.

Comment: No, that's something quite different (but it wasn't me who downvoted :))